# Copy object, retain one property link

Tags: javascript

Really struggling to achieve my desired effect. I basically need to create a link of objects, these objects will contain references to HTMLElements. When the **state** value is changed within this object a class should be either added/removed.

However I need to keep the link to this **state** when I create a copy of this object, so all other properties are unique and a new image is set within this copy, however if the state is to change in the first object, then it should also change within this new object, but reference the new image.

I have got the below script example, however when the state is being changed within the first object, the second object does not change. I believe i'm not keeping reference to the older object property.

```
<img src="https://mgreviewsblog.files.wordpress.com/2014/08/2014-ducati-899-panigale-white-16.jpg" alt="Image 1" class="responsive-img" data-lightbox-group="detail_gallery" data-lightbox-name="Gallery">
<img src="https://mgreviewsblog.files.wordpress.com/2014/08/2014-ducati-899-panigale-white-1.jpg" alt="Image 2" class="responsive-img" data-lightbox-group="detail_gallery" data-lightbox-name="Gallery">
<img src="https://mgreviewsblog.files.wordpress.com/2014/08/2014-ducati-899-panigale-white-3.jpg" alt="Image 3" class="responsive-img" data-lightbox-group="detail_gallery" data-lightbox-name="Gallery">

<script>
   let images = querySelectorAll('img');

   images = Array.from(images, function (elm) {
      var activeState = {
         _state: 0,
         object: null,
         set State(val) {
            if (this._state !== val) {
            switch(val) {
               case 0:
                  elm.classList.remove('active');
               break;
               case 1:
                  this.object.classList.add('active'); // Needs to reference image within object
               break;
            }
            this._state = val;
            };
         }
      };

      return {
         object: elm, // Store a reference to the image
         _active: activeState,
         get activeState() {
            this._active.object = this.object;
            return this._active;
         }
      };
   });


   // Duplicate the above object, but retain the state object,
   // however the object within the state needs to be different. 
   let clone = [];
   for (let i = 0; i < _.images.length; i++) {
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = _.images[i].object.src;
      img.alt = _.images[i].alt;

      newList.push({
         object: img,
         index: i,
         src: _.images[i].src,
         alt: _.images[i].alt,
         _active: _.images[i].activeState, // Retain reference to active state across objects
         get activeState() {
            this._active.object = this.object;
            return this._active;
         }
      });
   }
</script>
```

**Edit** 
Simplified version:

```
var test = {
    object: 'test1', 
    _active: { val: 0 },
    active: function(x) {
        this._active.val = x;
        console.log(this._active);
    }
  };
var test2 = {
    object: 'test1', 
    _active: test._value,
    active: test.value
  };
```

`_active.val` remains linked across objects, however if I change it like so `test2.active(2)` only the **test2** value is executed, **test** should execute as well.

Comment: @Jonasw this is more of example code, I have got a link of images, I just didnt want people guessing what was what...

Comment: I think you just need to apply the state after copying.

Answer (score 1):

I think your whole code is overly complex. I would do it like this:

```
function statify(el,state){
  var obj={
   get state(){
     return state;
   },
   set state(v){
    state=v;
    if(v){
      el.classList.add("active");
    }else{
      el.classList.remove("active");
    }
  },
  get el(){return el;},
  cloneTo(el){
   return statify(el,state);
  }
 };
 obj.state=state;
 return obj;
}
```

So you can use it like this:

```
var states=Array.from(images).map(image=>statify(image));

states[0].state=1;

var clone=states.map(function(state){
 var el=state.el;
 var img=document.createElement("img");
 img.src=el.src;
 return state.cloneTo(img);
});
```

http://jsbin.com/tuhehihade/edit?console